# Rails - Submitting multiple forms with one submit button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have a page for editing all users however I would like it so that I only have to click one submit button to update the users' details but at the moment I can only edit one and click the 'Update User' button to change that one user's details.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag edit_user_path do |form| %>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= form_for user do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sunday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :sunday %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :monday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :monday %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :tuesday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :tuesday %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :wednesday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :wednesday %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :thursday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :thursday %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :friday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :friday %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :saturday %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :saturday %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see that `submit_tag` at the bottom of the code does absolutely nothing however I would like it to update all the users' details. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Against:

```
<%= form_for user do |f| %>
```

use:

```
<%= fields_for "users[]", user do |f| %>
```

After that you will get in the controller parameters values for each user_id:

```
"users"=>{"user_id1"=>{"attr1"=>"value1"}, "user_id2"=>{"attr1"=>"value1"}
```

Also to make possible updating a collection of object a way to do it is to add an action to the `UsersController` like this:

```
def update_collection
  # Update users here
end
```

and update routing in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    match 'update_collection',  via: [:put, :patch]
  end
end
```

and use proper url in the main form:

```
<%= form_tag update_collection_users_path, method: :put do |form| %>
```

Comment: Makes the submit button do something, however it leads to an error saying `No route matches [POST] "/admin/users/1/edit"`

Comment: Try to replace `edit_user_path` in main form to `edit_users_path`, i think issue is here. Worked?

Comment: No sorry that gives an undefined local variable error

Comment: @ coreypizzle Sorry... it is not correct controller action. Give me a moment to examine that.

Comment: @coreypizzle I've improved my answer.

Comment: it seems that my form is attempting to POST rather than PUT as after clicking submit it gives the error, `No route matches [POST] "/admin/users/update_collection"`.

Comment: @coreypizzle `POST` is related to `create` controller action, I'm not sure why it is redirecting there, but I've updated my answer to avoid that behavior: see new `form_tag` definition. Also I fixed `routes` definition, there should be `match` against `put`.

Comment: Ah thank you. I suppose that I need to fill in def update_collection with update_attributes or something like that? You've been a great help so far!

Comment: @coreypizzle Yes, of course, you're right. Happy to help.

Comment: how can i use strong param in controller? it's now working ```users = params.require(:user).permit([:attr1, :attr2])```

Comment: @ChangwooRhee Try `params.require(:user).permit([:attr1, { attr1: [] }, :attr2, { attr2: [] }])`. A pair `[:attr, { attr: [] }]` is suitable for all the array-type parameters.